# Avoid Server Restart After Adding Endpoint Certificate

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I deployed clustered WSO2 APIM 4.0.0 and now I am checking it's API.
I am trying to add SSL certificate for the endpoint I am testing, but every time I add a certificate It requires a restart of the server to actually take effect.
I tried Adding to deployment.toml the following:

```
[transport.passthru_https.sender.ssl_profile]
interval = 600000
```

following this https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/design/endpoints/certificates/
but it didn't help.

I will be happy for your help,
Thanks.